# How to designate a printer using VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I’ve automated much of what I need using xlwings.

The final stage of my Python is printing a label.

```vb
Sub Print_Label()

    Print_Label Macro

    Prints Loan Label

    Range("C2:C8").Select

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show

    Selection.PrintOut Copies:=Range("A10"), Collate:=True

End Sub
```

The label is created using VBA and Python then triggers the print using the xlwings code.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(file.xlsm')

your_macro = wb.macro('Print_Label')

your_macro()
```

This prompts a pop up in Excel requesting which printer to use with an OK button. I need it to be a particular printer and run automatically in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Did it in the end - VBA -

```
Worksheets("Print").Activate
Worksheets("Print").Range("C2:C8").Select

Application.ActivePrinter = "ZDesigner ZM400 200 dpi (ZPL) on LAN_"
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=Worksheets("Print").Range("A10"), Collate:=True
```